How to show a required message when a user doesn't select a date in a date picker?
I am working on a form with a date picker. If the user submits the form without selecting a date, I need to display a "This field is required" message.
Here is the code I have so far:
<Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
                    <Controller
                      name='qobtrgtdt'
                      control={control}
                      rules={{
                        required: 'This field is required' 
                      }}
                      render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
                        <>
                          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale='en-gb'>
                            <DatePicker
                              disabled={isIssueToUser ? true : false}
                              value={ObsDataByID ? dayjs(ObsDataByID.qobtrgtdt) : ''}
                              label='OBSERVATION Target Dt'
                              onChange={(date: any) => {
                                onChange(date?.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
                                setValue('qobtrgtdt', date)
                              }}
                              format='DD/MM/YYYY'
                              minDate={dayjs()}
                              slotProps={{
                                textField: {
                                  size: 'small',
                                  margin: 'dense',
                                  style: { fontSize: 12 },
                                  error: Boolean(errors.qobtrgtdt),
                                  helperText: errors.qobtrgtdt ? errors.qobtrgtdt.message : '', 
                                  sx: {
                                    input: { color: textColor },
                                    label: { color: textColor }
                                  }
                                }
                              }}
                            />
                          </LocalizationProvider>
                        </>
                      )}
                    />
                  </Grid>

this is not work
error: Boolean(errors.qobtrgtdt),
                                  helperText: errors.qobtrgtdt ? errors.qobtrgtdt.message : '', 
                                  sx: {
                                    input: { color: textColor },
                                    label: { color: textColor }
                                  }

When the user tries to submit the form without selecting a date, the error message "This field is required" should appear below the date picker. If the user selects a date, the error message should disappear, and the form should submit normally.

In the helperText you provide, try checking message directly in the errors object like this: helperText: errors?.qobtrgtdt?.message ? errors.qobtrgtdt.message : undefined

I don't know React and DatePicker, but could you try to set the required attribute on <DatePicker>, like in this example: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-external-form
